How to test the difference between two regression coefficients run on different series?
I am writing my Bachelor thesis and would like to inquire about a particular statistical test that I would require. My paper requires me running a simple time series regression of Yi = A + BXi. I repeat this two times for two different financial indexes. Afterwards, I would like to test whether the two regression coefficients are statistically significant or not, that is whether B_S&P500 = B_Russel2000. All my previous Google endeavour has pointed to tests where the separate regressions are subsample of the same sample.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to proceed. Thank you so much and have a great day!
